# How do I make my image zoomable in a scrollview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, uiscrollview, zooming

I want my image called bildfraga to be zoomable. It is placed in the scrollview called scroll.
I am able to scroll the picture, but not zoom it.

This is my code when the image is shown:

```
  bildfraga = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dtk2.png"]];
scroll.contentSize = bildfraga.frame.size;
[scroll addSubview:bildfraga];
scroll.minimumZoomScale = 0.4;
scroll.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
[scroll setZoomScale:scroll.minimumZoomScale];

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scroll{
return bildfraga;
 }
```

But when I try to build this, I get an error saying something like: "Use of undeclared identifier 'viewForZoomingInScrollView'".

Thanks in advance!

/A noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the problem. Did you add UIScrollViewDelegate in your .h file?

Comment: No how do I do that? :O

I have written IBOutlet UIScrollView, but that is not what you mean right?

Comment: I added a line, so it is like this now: 

@interface DTK : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate>

Comment: It is still the same problem!

Comment: After placing the delegate in the .h file you have to set the ScrollView objects delegate to whatever class would be storing the method of the delegate, i say this cause you do not have to have each and every view hold a delegate for a certain object if the objects should respond the same but never mind that for now. So you should add [scroll setDelegate:self]; to the code above and it should work

Comment: I added this line: [scroll setDelegate:self]; under the setzoomscale line, but it still doesnt work :S

Comment: Where are you setting all the properties for the ScrollView? Also place some NSLogs to see if its even calling the viewForZoomingInScrollView method

Comment: It is not calling the viewForZoomingInScrollView, as I said in the description; I get an error. "Use of undeclared identifier 'viewForZoomingInScrollView'".

Comment: Dude sorry i don't have no idea then. How are u building the view in code or IB?

Comment: I got it! Apparently I wrote viewForZoomingInScrollView in a method, so it didn't work!